# Bash скрипт для работы с файлами и папками

Tags: linux, bash

Есть множество папок, которые находятся в определённой директории. В этих папках я ищу файлы с определённым расширением, `*.txt` для примера. Задача - найти те папки, в которых есть хотя бы один txt-файл и скопировать эту папку в другой каталог, к примеру `txtfiles`. Пробовал просто найти файндом и архивировать командой

```
tar cf txts.tar `find /root/test/1/ -name '*.txt' `
```

Но она добавляет в архив только сами txt файлы, а мне нужно полное копирование папки с ними (если txt находится в `/root/test/1/2/3/path`, то мне нужно именно полное копирование папки `1` в `/root/txtfiles` со всеми вложенными в неё файлами и директориями).

Comment: вывод find отправьте (`|`) скажем sed, которым вырежьте начало пути до нужной глубины (скажем ориентируясь на `/`). все это отправьте на sort и uniq что бы получить все папки строго по одному разу

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

rootdir="/d/tmp/123"
outdir="/d/tmp/txtfiles"

mkdir -p "$outdir"
pushd "$rootdir"
find . -mindepth 2 -name '*.txt' | xargs dirname | xargs -I{} cp -R --parents {} "$outdir"
popd
```

В переменной `rootdir` задаем каталог, в подкаталогах которого будем искать txt-файлы, найденные каталоги копируются в `outdir` с сохранением структуры командой `cp -R --parents`.

Comment: Он копирует только txt файлы, остальные файлы в папке - нет. В этом главная проблема. Как можно сделать так, чтоб при копировании все остальные файлы тоже сохранялись?

Comment: @quzty исправил

Answer (score 0):

если исходить из минимальной модификации вашей команды:

```
$ tar -cf txts.tar $(find /root/test/1/ -name '*.txt')
```

то можно добавить опцию `-printf '%h\n'` к другим опциям программы *find* и удалить дубликаты из результатов *find* с помощью программы *sort*:

```
$ tar -cf txts.tar $(find /root/test/1/ -name '*.txt' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)
```

---

подробности смотрите в `man find` и `man sort`.